# jquery remove function and removing more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I use the following code and only list one element then it works. When I want to remove both elements, it doesn't.  This is apart of my AJAX Success call:

```
 jQuery('#t_'+$cid, '#'+$cid).remove();
```

Can I not do this in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector has to be **ONE** string... So the coma separator for multiple selectors has to be **inside** the string.

This snippet works:

```js
let $cid = 1
 
jQuery('#t_'+$cid + ', #'+$cid).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t_1">t_1</div>
<span id="1">1</span>
```

Since that is starting to be messy and hard to nails down mistakes... When it comes to use variables in the selector(s) string, I suggest you to use some [templating literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). So this would be easier to read:

```
jQuery(`#t_${$cid}, #${$cid}`).remove();
```